# Count Sequential Dates in SQL

Tags: sql, date, count

So I've been looking around Stack and couldn't find a solution for my particular need.

So currently I'm trying to count to see a Pat's check in to a Practice - here is my table and some notes on what I'm trying to achieve (FYI - trying to resolve the solution using T-SQL)

1. A check in is considered when a the same Pat ID and the same Practice are present and the dates are consecutive
2. Other wise its a new check in

[image]

So there is a grouping column that indicates that the PatID and the PracticeIDs are the same and is ordering by dates - but - I can't seem to wrap my head around trying to look at the previous EndDate and seeing that the next Row's start date is consecutive.

I'm thinking it'll need some sort of Recursion/Cursor stuff going on but I'm not entirely sure where to start.

All help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query should only return rows from your table for `PatID`/`PracticeID` combinations for which there does NOT exist another row in your table for that same combination but with a `DateEnd` that is one date prior to the `DateStart`.

```
SELECT o.PatID, o.PracticeID
  FROM <table> o
 WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1
                     FROM <table> i
                    WHERE o.PatID = i.PatID
                      AND o.PracticeID = i.PracticeID
                      AND DATEDIFF(d, i.DateEnd, o.DateStart) = 1 )
 GROUP BY o.PatID, o.PracticeID
```

Note: the order of `i.DateEnd` and `o.DateStart` may need to be reversed.

Comment: Yes! Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks